# How many times is this for() loop iterating?

Tags: c, for-loop, 8051, keil

I'm not sure if i'm missing something in this for loop.
I expect it to execute the code inside the loop 8 times which will cause it to output 8characters on the LCD, but it loops 7 times and I see only seven characters.
I'm using a Keil compiler for this.
Please can anyone spot where I'm getting it wrong?

```
//keycount = 9
for ( iii = (keycount-1),jii = 0; iii > (keycount-8) && jii <8; iii--,jii++)
{
    LCD_Data_Write (jii,Digit_Mask[keybuff[iii]]);
}
```

Comment: iii>(keycount-8) here lies your problem. try this iii=>(keycount-8)

Comment: that means the loop counter iii starts at 8, and ends at 0, shouldn't the loop also iterate when iii=0 since the condition says to iterate also for iii=>0?

Comment: but your keycount-8 = 1 not equals to 0

Answer (score 1):

Okay, nothing in you loop body changes the variables that control it, so it's all down to the loop itself.

Simply write down the initial values and run the loop in your head:

```
//keycount = 9
for ( iii = (keycount-1),jii=0; iii>(keycount-8) && jii <8;iii--,jii++)

iii   jii   iii > 1   jii < 8  
---   ---   -------   -------
  8     0      Y         Y        iterate 1
  7     1      Y         Y        iterate 2
  6     2      Y         Y        iterate 3
  5     3      Y         Y        iterate 4
  4     4      Y         Y        iterate 5
  3     5      Y         Y        iterate 6
  2     6      Y         Y        iterate 7
  1     7      N         Y        exit loop
```

In other words, it only iterates seven times, not eight. I suspect you meant to iterate `iii` from 8 down to 1 (rather than 2). If that's the case, the whole loop can be replaced with something much simpler.

```
// keycount = 9
for (jii = 0; jii < 8; jii++)
    LCD_Data_Write (jii, Digit_Mask[keybuff[8-jii]]);
```

In fact, even if the values should have ranged from 7 down to 0, it's just a simple matter to change the call to:

```
LCD_Data_Write (jii, Digit_Mask[keybuff[7-jii]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this clearer, **transform the numbers by subtracting (keycount - 1)** just like you did in college when solving algebra equations (it had to be good for *something*! Today you know why :-). What you are left with is

```
 for (i = 0; i > -7; i--)
```

from which it is easy to see that the loop is iterated 7 times (with i taking values from 0 to -6). I've ignored the `jii<8` part which is always true and thus does not contribute to the result.

To answer the question where you are getting it wrong: it appears to be an **off-by-one** error. Did you mean `>=` where you wrote `>`?